# How to remove ok buttons and cancel in DateTimeField Flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

Is it possible to remove the two buttons incorporated in the picker?

Is it possible to avoid pressing the "ok" button to mark the date in the Field?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super old at this point, but someone in the future might come across this post and find it useful.

I managed to find a workaround with a few things:

- StatefulBuilder to handle the dialog state.
- CalendarDatePicker has the calendar UI that you can see in showDatePicker.
- Material class to be able to mount the CalendarDatePicker on top.

```
Future<DateTime?> showDatePickerDialog(context) async {
  DateTime initialDate = DateTime.now();
  DateTime firstDate = DateTime(2021);
  DateTime lastDate = DateTime(2023);
  DateTime date = await showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 64.0),
                  child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
                    String formattedDate =
                        DateFormat('E, LLL d').format(selectedDate);
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0),
                          height: 100.0,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                selectedDate.year.toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 4.0),
                              Text(
                                formattedDate,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 24.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              CalendarDatePicker(
                                initialDate: initialDate,
                                firstDate: firstDate,
                                lastDate: lastDate,
                                onDateChanged: (date) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedDate = date;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                child: TextButton(
                                  child: Text('OK'),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.pop(context, selectedDate);
                                  },
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
  return date;
}
```

This has 1 important limitation (as of the moment of posting, will update if I can find something): For some reason, it uses all the space available. I've only been able to reduce the size using padding. Probably I'm unable to solve this because it's currently 5 am.

For my specific use case, I needed to force users into picking a date, so `barrierDismissible: false` in my showDialog and WillPopScope with `onWillPop: () async => false` did the trick for me. You may not include this if you don't need it.

Feel free to style this properly, I just went for the barely good enough.

Edit: You can avoid the "OK" button using `Navigator.pop(context, selectedDate);` inside `onDateChanged`

Answer (score 0):

To discuss about your issue, we can split it into these two parts

### 1. Can we hide Cancel and OK Button

Yes, we can

#### Final Code

```dart
Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime chosenDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime(2020, 6, 21),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020, 5, 1),
      lastDate: DateTime(2020, 7, 1),
      confirmText: "", // to Hide it, we use this
      cancelText: "", // to Hide it, we use this
    );
    print("chosenDate");
    print(chosenDate);
}
```

### 2. Can we mark date without having OK button

No, we cannot. At the example above, I printed out return value of chosenDate.

[image: Return Value of Chosen Date]

#### Flutter Material Widget

Because, basically, Flutter needs to execute `_handleOk` method, to destroy `DatePicker` window, and return Value through await.

```dart
// flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/pickers/date_picker_dialog.dart
// Line 301
void _handleOk() {
    if (_entryMode == DatePickerEntryMode.input) {
      final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;
      if (!form.validate()) {
        setState(() => _autoValidate = true);
        return;
      }
      form.save();
    }
    Navigator.pop(context, _selectedDate);
  }
```